# In what situations would "self-plagiarism" be authorized by a professor?

Tags: professorship, plagiarism, self-plagiarism, policy

A lot of universities say "Cannot submit this work in whole or in part to another class without prior written consent by the instructor."

What is an example of a situation where a student would get consent for this?

Comment: If it is obvious that they know how to do the stuff and it's pointless to waste their time. Depends on the policy of the department.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand the question. Obviously, an example of such a situation would be the situation that the instructor does not care whether a submitted solution was already submitted in another class.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs: It isn't usually a matter of department policy, in my experience - it is simply up to the instructor to decide whether resubmitting previous work would fulfill their own course's learning objectives.  Often there could be conditional consent: "you can use your existing work as a base, but must add sections to cover topics X,Y,Z."

Comment: This seems very opinion-based. But if I have to contribute my 2 cents then I will only approve if the previous work has not decreased the challenge of the new work significantly, or is a meaningful extension of the previous work. For instance, if a student developed a questionnaire in course A (research method), and then in my course B (data analysis) the student wants to use the same questionnaire to collect analyzable data. I will have no problem with that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I first note that the idea that students' work is somehow not a part of their personal body of work, thus owned by them, and re-purpose-able however they like, has always struck me as very strange. In fact, this seems to me quite contrary to any notion that universities are creating intellectuals and scholars. That is, there is a powerful implicit assumption that students would never do anything at all if not commanded to do so by instructors in officially scheduled courses, so somehow do not deserve credit for any work, and do not truly "own" it.

I myself have absolutely no objection to anyone's re-use of work they happened to do before I asked them to do it. :)

All the better, in fact, if they had the sense and drive to do it before being asked.

I much prefer the idea that each student develops a body of expertise, often expressed in write-ups of various technical sorts, if only as notes-to-self, which can be brought to bear in various situations. *Not* that everyone is required to give up all fruits of their own prior work, to avoid some highly commodified, artifactual stigmas about "self-plagiarization". Sometimes the answer to a question does not change just because it is asked repeatedly.

Comment: My published papers are part of my personal body of work, but I can’t re-publish them in new journals.  It’s not about ownership, it’s about expectation of originality.  It *is* up to an instructor to decide whether to ask for original work only, and I agree with you there’s often no reason to do so — but equally there sometimes are good reasons; it’s not an unreasonable thing for an instructor to require.

Comment: @PLL, what's the point of "originality" per se, though?

Comment: @paul I agree with part of what you wrote (I'll remain strategically mum as to which part exactly :-)), but it's worth noting that both committing, and objecting to, self-plagiarism make much less sense in the context of math. It's simply not an issue we care much about in math because students will almost never have an occasion to gain an advantage through self-plagiarism, and when they do, it will usually be a _fair_ advantage. This is not true in the humanities for example where a student can conceivably reuse an essay many times in a way that truly undermines our educational efforts.

Comment: (To clarify, self-plagiarism is still a serious concern for math in the context of people who attempt to republish papers containing already published ideas and content. I was referring to self-plagiarism in the context of homework assignments and such when I said it is not a big concern in math.)

Comment: I like this answer.  Sometimes it's easier to answer a question by looking at the opposite case -- here, what types of recycling of one's own writing would be problematic?  I have come across one.  I was copy-editing a paper in the social sciences and discovered that the author had lifted whole swaths of text from something else he had *published* into the article I was editing.  But he didn't use quotation marks and he didn't cite the other work.  *That's* a problem.

Comment: @DanRomik - Other fields I can think of where recycling old work is not a problem are music composition and painting etc.  As long as the new work based on the old is fresh and interesting.

Comment: @Dan: "This is not true in the humanities for example where a student can conceivably reuse an essay many times in a way that truly undermines our educational efforts." I took **many** humanities courses as an undergrad, and this worry about reuse/undermining doesn't seem very plausible to me.  In each course I took we read and discussed new works and the essays all concerned those works, so the issue never came up....

Comment: ...Moreover, every essay that I got assigned had a very specific question, often one that was closely related to lectures and class discussions.  If the same essay really works well in more than one class, I wonder about the instructor's pedagogical integrity: are they simply repeating themselves or being overly generic?  Anyway, if I got asked exactly the same question that I had already answered, I agree with paul garrett: if you answered the question well before, it seems to undermine what you did to demand a new answer.  If you want a new answer, ask a new question: that's not so hard.

Answer (score 4):

I have seen advanced classes where a previous paper was substantially revised, with the approval of the instructor. This is likely to be allowed only when the new work is clearly building on the old work, rather than using the old work as a shortcut. That is, it most often is approved because the student has a passion for the topic and wants to dive in much deeper in a subsequent class; it is *not* generally approved because a student has "already done the work" and will essentially be turning in the same thing twice.

Usually this happens on a case-by-case basis, but I know of at least one advanced writing course where the actual assignment was to revise a paper that had already been written for some previous class. This allowed the professor and students to focus on the mechanics of research-based writing, without having to actually conduct most of the research.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some examples from my Department:

1. In their second year class on English for Academic Purposes (EAP), students are asked to provide an example of assignments they submitted in their first year. Their task is to evaluate their earlier writing in terms of the quality of academic English not the context or technical content of the work. They are graded on the basis of this evaluation. Students find this especially enlightening because they can see firsthand the improvements they have made in their study of English. For example, they are able to see how much more proficient they are in the skill of citations and bibliography construction.
2. At the end of the third year, students submit a research proposal for a methods course. This proposal is revisited in the beginning of the next year, serving as the basis for their undergraduate dissertation.
3. At the start of a course on basic biostatistics, students collect data and pool them. The data are used in four other biostatistics courses over the next three years to demonstrate techniques of increasing complexity.

In each of these situations, we have strict controls applied through the moderation process that prevents the assessment criterion from being applied more than once when the material is re-used. Take, for example, the third scenario above. One of the marking criteria during the data collection period is, say, appropriate construction of a Likert scale question. This criterion does not exist in any assessment task subsequent it. This prevents us from passing along a mark from assessment to assessment over time.

Answer (score 0):

Some examples I have encountered in my time:

1. As @Blue-Footed Booby's Blue Feet (I love typing that name) notes, there are occasionally methods sequence classes where students are expected to carry over projects from one course to the next. For these, it's often allowable to use the same text for justifying the project, sample collection, etc. between classes, because there's only so many ways to rewrite a section on the study population.
2. There was a class that many of my cohort took as PhDs where the main project was designing and heavily documenting a planned study. The next semester, there was a grant writing class - it was again expected that these would be chopped up and reconstituted for portions of the grant.

Answer (score 0):

The rule is there because universities believe that someone should not get credit twice for the same work, as that would give that person an unfair advantage over other students.

If you have work you already did which you want to use in order to build upon the results, you can usually do so, as long as you reference your original work so that it is clear what you are doing. Quotation marks should be used for copied text, but it's better not to have too much quoted text.

You should, however, consult with your professor in order to make sure it is ok and which format should be used to reference the previous paper.

Comment: Why do you think it's unfair to other students? What difference would it make if that work was produced originally in either class? Why should it matter what to the other students what the student gets in another class with the same paper if it was still their own work. The only argument for it being "unfair" is the fact that other students will have to spend more time making a whole new paper. And if you argue that the student isn't learning anything with the same submission twice, one could also argue that there is always some knowledge that could be overlooked in a course and not learned.

Comment: Each course is unique and offers unique feedback to students even if it's a paper from another class, so their is always room for the student to learn more on the topic they chose. If a student does well in a certain topic, and captures the goals of the course and learning goals, then it's just redundant to look at a different topic and just for the purpose of doing work and end up having your mark not truly reflecting your competence and understanding of the course topics/concepts.

Comment: I don't make the rules but I see the reasons for them. Yes, the main factor is the amount of time it takes to complete an assignment. If one student doesn't have to put in this time and effort and another does, the first student has more time to work toward another course. Legally, a submission for a grade constitutes a "publication" and so it is self-plagiarism to make another identical "publication". As for learning from the feedback, you actually learn a lot more by doing the work than just from getting feedback.

Comment: I think it's kind of subjective to say it's unfair for the time consumption reason. The main focus is the content, not the process of doing work. It is up to the student to choose the number of courses they wish to take, and what course content they wish to deal with. Can you elaborate on your "publication" point? I know what you mean if a prof publishes works in journals, but also, again the same piece of work can contribute different information/knowledge in more than one context of a class, or subjective or work study, etc.

Comment: What if someone were to take a class that that they had an expert background in, but had no prior work available to submit to it? They would still be taking the time to produce a new piece of work, even though they already know what the assignment is trying to teach. Even if they are writing in a new context about something they haven't written about before, they would still be talking about this topic in the glow of the same concepts that the course is teaching and it would be the same concepts every time, no matter the content that the concepts are taught through.

Comment: The reason why I said that a submission counts as a publication is because future submissions or publications of the same work, or a work containing some of the same text, images, etc. would constitute self-plagiarism unless the quoted or copied work is properly attributed. This is why Turnitin checks all previous work, even the student's own.

Comment: But when a student submits a paper for a measly second, third, or even fourth year class, it's not really a serious case like a real publication by a professor and doesn't constitute professional work for use in the real and/or academic realms. It's not remotely the same context or the same magnitude of a problem to the real world. I think it really would just depend on the learning goals of the professor for each course, which is why this type of thing is allowed with the professor's permission, as outlined in many schools' academic integrity policies.

Comment: Otherwise, it would be objectively forbidden in the academic world.

Comment: It _is_ forbidden in the academic world. The exception is where permission is expressly granted. I wonder if you are now asking something different than your original question. It is hard to say what an individual professor would consider grounds for giving permission for resubmitting the same work, as each person is different. In any event, most institutions do have a policy forbidding students to self-plagiarise in submitted work, and the reasons for this have already been given above. People who publish plagiarised work often face stiffer penalties than students but that is another issue.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. Currently, it is only a subjective issue from prof to prof. Objectively it is not forbidden, since not everyone agrees. You only need to ask in order to see what the each specific professor's attitude is towards it. In an objective sense, not all people agree on it to be forbidden. If it was objective, then no one would be able to do it regardless of each professor's take on it and regardless of the course. It still relates to my original question. I'm just critiquing the reasons given above and debating the whole issue.